How to calculate profit margin for products in Shopware 5?
I am trying to calculate the profit margin for my products in Shopware 5 system.
Basically, from what I have found out, the formula to do this is:
profit margin = (selling price - purchase price) / selling price * 100
The selling and purchase prices are required.
So this is what I have done, I am trying to pull out the details and then make the calculation:
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $cost = $product['purchaseprice'];

    // How do I get this?
    $sellingPrice = '';

    // Calculate profit margin (in percentage)
    $profitMargin = ($sellingPrice - $cost) / $sellingPrice * 100;
}

But the problem is that I don't know how to get the $sellingPrice, as this price is not displayed in the backend.
How do I get the $sellingPrice so I can make this calculation?
Thanks!

where did you get the product from? plain SQL query or did you use some service like the \Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Service\Core\ProductService
